# SQL Delete not gettng the results i need. subquery, outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to meet and I can't seem to figure out how to delete records all a database entry.

I have a table that gets updated daily
Structure

```
    ID  Name eventnum state
     1   a    1        4
     2   a    1        2
     3   a    1        3
     4   a    1        9
     5   b    3        1
```

Due to the things completely out of my control users are allowed to input the same information, however on a nightly job when column "state" has an entry of 9 delete all rows of data that have the same name and eventnum (so id 1-4 will be delete).

In Oracle I can do this with a subquery but in Microsoft SQL it looks like I can only pass one column in a IN statement.
Any ideas?

Comment: are you want to delete all records from a single table?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but as for your statement regarding one column... `WHERE Col1 IN (...) OR/AND Col2 IN (...)` ?

Comment: Your question would have been that much clearer if you had posted the Oracle query.

Comment: @bjones they will have been trying `DELETE FROM table WHERE (Name,EventNum) IN (SELECT Name, EventNum FROM table WHERE State=9)` presumably. That can't be reproduced that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a correlated subquery for this or a `JOIN` to a subquery. You might also be able to just use a simple self-join (the last query listed).

```
DELETE MT
FROM
    MyTable MT
INNER JOIN (SELECT name, eventnum FROM MyTable WHERE [state] = 9) SQ ON
    SQ.name = MT.name AND
    SQ.eventnum = MT.eventnum
```

Or:

```
DELETE MT1
FROM
    MyTable MT1
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM MyTable MT2
        WHERE
            MT2.name = MT1.name AND
            MT2.eventnum = MT1.eventnum AND
            MT2.[state] = 9
    )
```

Or:

```
DELETE MT2
FROM
    MyTable MT1
INNER JOIN MyTable MT2 ON
    MT2.name = MT1.name AND
    MT2.eventnum = MT1.eventnum
WHERE
    MT1.[state] = 9
```

Comment: Yes, and I up-voted it. That's no reason not to add a more complete answer.

Comment: I ended up using the inner join option. I know it a little bit better, both worked well thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

TSQL doesn't support tuples in `in` but it is easy to replace this with `EXISTS` with an equality predicate on all desired columns.

```
DELETE T1
FROM YourTable T1
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM YourTable T2
WHERE T2.State=9 
  AND T1.Name = T2.Name 
  AND T1.EventNum = T2.EventNum
)
```

Comment: I wish I could have marked both answers you and Tom H's they both work.. I ended up using the inner join option as a understand it a little bit better. thanks for the help!

Comment: @CrazyITWannaBe no problem! it's entirely your prerogative to pick whichever one you preferred.